# publishing a cv2 image with cv_bridge

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, libopencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a basic node that reads an image from a local folder and publishes it. However, the topic is empty, i can not display the image when i use the image viewer. The cv2 image is being loaded correctly because i can display it with cv2.imshow function so the problem is the way i convert it to imgmsg.

I am not sure if this line works as it should:

```
image_message = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image, "passthrough")
```

The whole node is as simple as this:

```
class image_publisher:
 def __init__(self):
  self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("image_topic",Image)
  cv_image = cv2.imread('/Pictures/image.png',0)
  self.bridge = CvBridge()
  image_message = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image, "passthrough")
  self.image_pub.publish(image_message)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327682/publishing-a-cv2-image-with-cv_bridge/) by [rosberrypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31252/rosberrypi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2019-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As PeteBlackerThe3rd suggested you're publishing the image in your **init** method right after the publisher is created. Here is an example class that works for your case:

```
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import time


class ImagePublisher(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.node_rate = 1

    self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("image_topic", Image)
    cv_image = cv2.imread('/Pictures/image.png',0)
    self.bridge = CvBridge()

    try:
      self.image_message = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image, "passthrough")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
      print(e)

    time.sleep(5)
    self.image_pub.publish(self.image_message)

  def doSmth(self):
    rospy.loginfo('its working!')
    # self.image_pub.publish(self.image_message)

  def run(self):
    loop = rospy.Rate(self.node_rate)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      self.doSmth()
      loop.sleep()
```

If you want to publish the image only once then use the time.sleep() in your  **init** . Otherwise if you want to publish on some rate then uncomment the publish line in doSmth().

EDIT:
WIth image_view I am encountering conversion errors due to encoding/color formats. In my case it is trying to convert image from '8UC3' to 'bgr8' so I had to change this line:

```
self.image_message = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image, encoding="bgr8")
```

Now I can see the image using:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/image_topic
```

Anyway the initial problem you had was still related to publishing the image in your **init** method right after the publisher is create.

Also note that if you are publishing it only once as in your example, make sure to run image_view before you run your node.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1